# Proving that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^5-2n+7}=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning, limits-without-lhopital

In my assignment I have to prove the following:

$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^5-2n+7}=1$$

I don't know how to start, I believe it has to do with the squeeze theorem, but I can't be sure.

EDIT: can't use L'Hospital.
Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Do you know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Can I use it?

Comment: I gave you a hint in my answer how to use it. And your idea of using the squeeze theorem sounds good as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you know that

> $$
> \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1.
> $$

Then you may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sqrt[n]{7} <\sqrt[n]{n^5-2n+7}<\sqrt[n]{n^5+0+n^5}
$$ or
$$
\sqrt[n]{7} <\sqrt[n]{n^5-2n+7}<\sqrt[n]{2}\times \left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^5
$$ and you may conclude easily.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** we have $7\leq n^5-2n+7\leq n^5+7n^5=8n^5$ for big enough $n$. With $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{p}$$ for $p>0$ look for an application of the sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $A=\sqrt[n]{n^5-2n+7}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln(n^5-2n+7)}n$ which is of the form $\dfrac00$

hence safely apply L'Hospital

Comment: Thank you, however I'm far too early in my course to use L'Hospital.